# ContentFinder Issue in request

Tags: aem

I have the request URL which contains the #cf, result is page not getting load. But if I remove cf# it starts load. Don't know where the exact issue be, have cleared the browser cache. I just installed the package, after that problem coming, but now I removed it, still problem persist.

localhost:4502/cf#/content/geometrixx.html --> Page not displayed and

localhost:4502/content/geometrixx.html --> Page gets displayed

Comment: Are you getting any errors, either in the developer console (i.e. in browser, e.g. Firebug) or in the main error.log?

Comment: Yes, I am getting an error in firebug : TypeError: CQ.wcm.ContentFinderTab.getAccountComboConfig is not a function
...   "url": "/bin/wcm/contentfinder/product/view.json/etc/commerce/products"      ...

Comment: Keep in mind that if you delete & uninstalling the package are two different actions — if you simply delete the Zip file in the Package Manager, whatever modifications the package made are still present in your system. If you install your package in a fresh environment, does the same issue occur? — It looks like it may be your package that's at fault.

Comment: Thanks, got the error & fixed, actually there was existing wcm/extensions/... folder inside app